Set True to duplicate records that occur within 1 hour window
I’d like to set is_duplicate to TRUE for records that occur within a 1-hour window of an earlier record.
The rule is that each record should check against the most recent prior record where is_duplicate is FALSE, not just the immediately preceding row.
For example, in row 3, the timestamp should be compared with row 1 (the last non duplicate) rather than row 2, which is already marked as a duplicate.
I know that this might need to be done in a post processing job, but is there any way to do this purely with SQL?
I'm running these queries in Athena.



Row
data_timestamp
is_duplicate
explanation




1
2024-09-30 15:55:50
FALSE
there's no preceding logging


2
2024-09-30 16:55:50
TRUE
diff with row 1 is less than or equal to 1 hour


3
2024-09-30 17:36:50
FALSE
diff with row 1 is larger than 1 hour


4
2024-09-30 17:40:50
TRUE
diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour


5
2024-09-30 17:50:03
TRUE
diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour


6
2024-09-30 20:27:24
FALSE
diff with row 3 is larger than 1 hour


7
2024-09-30 21:27:24
TRUE
diff with row 6 is less than or equal to 1 hour


8
2024-09-30 22:22:24
FALSE
diff with row 6 is larger than 1 hour



Using window functions on Athena didn't work since it still doesn't know which row is the most recent prior record while calculating is_duplicate


I’d like to set is_duplicate to TRUE for records that occur within a 1-hour window of an earlier record.

As far as I understand this can be rephrased as "starting the first record all the following within an 1 hour window should be marked as duplicates, then skip to the next following record", which is what can be "easily" done with the MATCH_RECOGNIZE function (AFAIK Athena should support it) :
-- sample data
WITH dataset(Row, data_timestamp, target_is_duplicate) as (
    values (1,  timestamp '2024-09-30 15:55:50', FALSE),
    (2, timestamp '2024-09-30 16:55:50', TRUE),
    (3, timestamp '2024-09-30 17:36:50', FALSE),
    (4, timestamp '2024-09-30 17:40:50', TRUE),
    (5, timestamp '2024-09-30 17:50:03', TRUE),
    (6, timestamp '2024-09-30 20:27:24', FALSE),
    (7, timestamp '2024-09-30 21:27:24', TRUE),
    (8, timestamp '2024-09-30 22:22:24', FALSE)
)

-- query
SELECT * FROM dataset MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
     ORDER BY data_timestamp, row
     MEASURES
              A.row != row AS is_duplicate -- our target value
     ALL ROWS PER MATCH -- take all rows
     AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW -- arguably self explanatory 
     PATTERN (A B*) -- pattern, A is the first row in the group, followed by zero or more records within the "window"
     DEFINE
              B AS data_timestamp <= FIRST(data_timestamp) + interval '1' hour
     )
order by row;

Output:



Row
data_timestamp
is_duplicate
target_is_duplicate




1
2024-09-30 15:55:50
false
false


2
2024-09-30 16:55:50
true
true


3
2024-09-30 17:36:50
false
false


4
2024-09-30 17:40:50
true
true


5
2024-09-30 17:50:03
true
true


6
2024-09-30 20:27:24
false
false


7
2024-09-30 21:27:24
true
true


8
2024-09-30 22:22:24
false
false




This is awesome, thanks so much for this! Had to spend some time to understand how it works under the hood. And it's impressive that this didn't even impact the query performance (I ran this on 7M+ rows)

This is actually a fun challenge, and there probably is a way to use the fancy Trino/Presto WINDOW frame definition to make it work with window functions, however I resorted to using aggregates. The idea is to produce an array of data_timestamps using the array_agg function and then apply reduce function, building a parallel array tracking the is_duplicate flag that can be referred to during the reduction operation by applying filter function. Below is the code - I used the original data in table for reference, cleaned it up, aggregated and reduced in CTEs, and finally unnested back into rows and joined to the original dataset to compare - below is the output and the query I ran on Athena:



data_timestamp
is_duplicate_computed
is_duplicate
explanation




2024-09-30 15:55:50
false
false
there's no preceding logging


2024-09-30 16:55:50
true
true
diff with row 1 is less than or equal to 1 hour


2024-09-30 17:36:50
false
false
diff with row 1 is larger than 1 hour


2024-09-30 17:40:50
true
true
diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour


2024-09-30 17:50:03
true
true
diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour


2024-09-30 20:27:24
false
false
diff with row 3 is larger than 1 hour


2024-09-30 21:27:24
true
true
diff with row 6 is less than or equal to 1 hour


2024-09-30 22:22:24
false
false
diff with row 6 is larger than 1 hour



with data as
(
    select 1 "row", '2024-09-30 15:55:50' data_timestamp, 'FALSE' is_duplicate, 'there''s no preceding logging' explanation
    union all
    select 2, '2024-09-30 16:55:50', 'TRUE', 'diff with row 1 is less than or equal to 1 hour'
    union all
    select 3, '2024-09-30 17:36:50', 'FALSE', 'diff with row 1 is larger than 1 hour'
    union all
    select 4, '2024-09-30 17:40:50', 'TRUE', 'diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour'
    union all
    select 5, '2024-09-30 17:50:03', 'TRUE', 'diff with row 3 is less than or equal to 1 hour'
    union all
    select 6, '2024-09-30 20:27:24', 'FALSE', 'diff with row 3 is larger than 1 hour'
    union all
    select 7, '2024-09-30 21:27:24', 'TRUE', 'diff with row 6 is less than or equal to 1 hour'
    union all
    select 8, '2024-09-30 22:22:24', 'FALSE', 'diff with row 6 is larger than 1 hour'
),
data_clean as
(
    select
        "row",
        cast(data_timestamp as timestamp) data_timestamp,
        if(is_duplicate = 'TRUE', true, false) is_duplicate,
        explanation
    from
        data
),
data_agg as
(
    select
        array_agg(data_timestamp order by data_timestamp) timestamps
    from
        data_clean
),
data_dedup as
(
    select
        reduce
        (
            timestamps,
            array[],
            (s, x) -> s || (x, if(date_diff('minute', element_at(filter(s, y -> y[2] = false), -1)[1], x) <= 60, true, false)),
            s -> s
        ) deduped_timestamps
    from
        data_agg
)
select
    dt.ts[1] data_timestamp,
    dt.ts[2] is_duplicate_computed,
    dc.is_duplicate,
    dc.explanation
from
    data_dedup
    cross join unnest(deduped_timestamps) as dt(ts)
    inner join data_clean dc on dc.data_timestamp = dt.ts[1]
order by 1
;


MATCH_RECOGNIZE arguably would be a better option than window functions.

I agree and thank you for posting an example of it

This is an interesting approach too, thanks for taking some time to share this @AleksandrKrymskiy
